Need help repurposing led motion detector to trip 3v relay instead of turning on leds
I've got what seemed to me to be a straightforward hack to repurpose a little motion detector light to trip a 3v relay instead but I'm running into issues.
The motion detector circuit runs on 3 AAAs and outputs 3v at L+ and L- to run a 3 led light strip (see pic 1) when motion is detected. I've disconnected the positive wire to the light strip and instead connected L+ to one of the contacts for the 3v coil on the relay (pic 1 and pic 2 red wire) and connected L- to the other coil contact (black wire).
Since L+ and L- put out 3v when the motion detector is tripped, that should trip the relay right? As I've disconnected the led light strip and routed the 3v to the relay instead.
Right now though what's happening instead is my wires from the batteries are burning.
I've tried connecting the black wire (2nd contact of coil) to the negative of the battery pack but this started melting my wires again.
What am i getting wrong here?
TIA
-Art
pic 1

pic 2

3v relay (CIT J1071)


Your relay is drawing way more power than the LEDs it is replacing. If the LEDs are in parallel and drawing 20mA each, then the relay is drawing twice as much current and creating 4x the heat. Try using a solid state relay.

I thought the point of a relay is to apply a certain voltage across the coil to close (or open) a switch that completes a totally separated circuit. Do all relays require high levels of current? And I guess next question would be: any neat tricks to protect the rest of the ciruit from the extra current draw?

Can I add a separate power source for the relay (another battery pack of 3 AAAs) so cutrent draw wouldn't damage the PIR circuit? If so, how would that look like?

Or could I simply remove the PIR from the led circuit (I don't need or want) and power it and the relay from the 3 AAAs?

My other confusion is why would the battery wires melt? The relay is 0.4W, which is I = 0.4 / 3v * 1000 is 133mA. That's not a lot of piwer. Heavier duty wire? Feedback loop or short causing the heat?

The datasheet (https://www.citrelay.com/Catalog%20Pages/RelayCatalog/J107.pdf) says 0.36W for the coil which matches with the 25 ohms, so I don't know where you got 0.04W. That means a 120mA current draw.  I don't know what size the wires are but 120mA isn't a lot; maybe you have something hooked up wrong.

Figured out why wires melting. Something got shorted so batteries were shorting back to themselves causing a lot of heat.

vir: you're right, I realized my mistake on that. Relay is indeed 0.4w. Thanks for verifying that the current draw isn't a lot  Gives me a bit of hope I can still get this working
